# Eclipse RCP: Open Split Screen Editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I'm looking for a way to open a split screen editor in an Eclipse RCP application programmatically.
From an open Editor I want to open another Editor. The purpose is to compare the content of Editor1 with the content of Editor2.

What I have is the following, but this creates a split screen Editor containing the content of Editor2 twice:

```
MPart editorPart = editor.getSite().getService(MPart.class);
if (editorPart == null) {
    return;
}
editorPart.getTags().add(IPresentationEngine.SPLIT_HORIZONTAL);
```

I think best would be opening Editor2 left or below the current editor, so it has its own tab and close button.

Comment: Are you looking for something like the [Compare Editor](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-25.htm)?

Comment: The answer posted below, nails it. Just open an editor next or below the current editor. The Compare Editor would be second choise.

Comment: I don't know your actual use case, but if _the purpose is to compare the content_, then a compare editor is the natural choice when using Eclipse.

Comment: I agree, but the compare editor comes with a lot of dependencies. The "org.eclipse.compare" bundle depends also on "org.eclipse.ui.ide", which is not suited for my RCP application.

Comment: Yes, that's reasonable. I was under the wrong impression that you were targeting the IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below splits an editor by inserting one editor into another. This is what DnD for editor tabs does in Eclipse.

```
   /**
     * Inserts the editor into the container editor.
     * 
     * @param ratio
     *            the ratio
     * @param where
     *            where to insert ({@link EModelService#LEFT_OF},
     *            {@link EModelService#RIGHT_OF}, {@link EModelService#ABOVE} or
     *            {@link EModelService#BELOW})
     * @param containerEditor
     *            the container editor
     * @param editorToInsert
     *            the editor to insert
     */
    public void insertEditor(float ratio, int where, MPart containerEditor, MPart editorToInsert) {
        IWorkbenchWindow window = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow();
        EModelService service = window.getService(EModelService.class);
        MPartStack toInsert = getPartStack(editorToInsert);

        MArea area = getArea(containerEditor);
        MPartSashContainerElement relToElement = area.getChildren().get(0);
        service.insert(toInsert, (MPartSashContainerElement) relToElement, where, ratio);
    }

    private MPartStack getPartStack(MPart childPart) {
        MStackElement stackElement = childPart;
        MPartStack newStack = BasicFactoryImpl.eINSTANCE.createPartStack();
        newStack.getChildren().add(stackElement);
        newStack.setSelectedElement(stackElement);
        return newStack;
    }

    private MArea getArea(MPart containerPart) {
        MUIElement targetParent = containerPart.getParent();
        while (!(targetParent instanceof MArea))
            targetParent = targetParent.getParent();
        MArea area = (MArea) targetParent;
        return area;
    }
```

Examples of the use the `insert` method are below:

```
insertEditor(0.5f, EModelService.LEFT_OF, containerPart, childPart);
insertEditor(0.5f, EModelService.BELOW, containerPart, childPart);
```

In passing, code in class [`SplitDropAgent2`](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/bundles/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt/src/org/eclipse/e4/ui/workbench/addons/dndaddon/SplitDropAgent2.java) is responsible for the DnD capability of the editor tabs.

Comment: Great, this does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!